# Logic - Having a alphabet and a set of words from that language,is it true that there exists a regular expression

Tags: logic, automata

So I found the following exercise and I have quite the trouble finding a way to solve it :

Having a alphabet {0,1,2,3,4} we define a set of words A, from that language in the following way(inductive definition of A) :

- 0,1 $\in$ A ,
- if $ \alpha \in A $, then $0\alpha \in A$ and $\alpha1 \in A $,
- if $ \alpha \in A $, then $42\alpha2 \in A$,
- if $\alpha,\beta \in A$ ,then $2\alpha3\beta2 \in A$;

Is it true that there exists a regular expression r, such that :
L(r)=A

Comment: Have you tried the pumping lemma?

Comment: Not exactly sure how to use it It came across my mind

Comment: I think $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ is your _alphabet_ rather than a _language_.

Comment: Then how about the Myhill-Nerode theorem? The prefixes $(42)^n$ for different $n$ are all distinguishable, since if $i\ne j$ then $(42)^u02^i$ is in the language but $(42)^j02^i$ is not.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yea thank you i am not a native speaker sorry

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A$ is regular.
For this language $A,$ the pumping lemma says that if $A$ is regular then
there exists an integer $n$ such that for all $x\in A$ such that $|x|\geq n,$
there exist $u, v, w \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}^*$ 
such that

1. $x = uvw$
2. $|uv|\leq n$
3. $|v|\geq 1$
4. For all $i \geq 0,$ $uv^iw \in A.$

Given such an $n$, 
consider the string $x = (42)^n02^n,$ which is in $A.$
Then we must be able to write $(42)^n02^n=uvw$
where $u, v, w$ satisfy the conditions given above.
But $uv$ is shorter than $(42)^n$
(note that $n\geq1$ by the conditions 2 and 3, so $n < 2n$),
hence when we write $uv^2w$ we have just "pumped" some extra
$4$s or $2$s into the $(42)^n$ part of $(42)^n02^n.$
As a result, the string $uv^2w$ has more than $2n$ symbols
from $\{2,4\}$ before the $0,$ which implies that there are
more than $n$ $2$s after the $0,$ but there are only $n$ of those
(because $w$ includes the suffix $02^n$).
This is a contradiction, so the assumption that $A$ is regular must be false.

That's a rough intuition of how the proof works. You would want to
figure out a more formal argument.

Perhaps $x = 2^n0(302)^n$ would be an easier string to argue about,
because then $uv = 2^m$ for $m\leq n$ and you can easily write
$uv^2w$ in a form that shows it is not in $A.$